# How to SQLCipher for a pre made database

Tags: android, sqlcipher

I have a 15mb database  .

I need to encrypt it , so it can't be readable easily .

I'm using `SQLCipher` , it works fine for a new database but I've made my database and I need to encode it now . How can I do so ?

My database is in asset folder or will be downloaded when user runs the app for the first time, I don't want my app to get data from internet because it should be an offline application.

How can I encrypt my database with all it's data?

Comment: could someone help me ? Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the `sqlcipher_export(…)` function, specifically example 1 found in the documentation [here](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#sqlcipher_export).  You can also find an example of this within the SQLCipher for Android test suite [here](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/net/zetetic/tests/ImportUnencryptedDatabaseTest.java).